# Html video not opening Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

This is the code I tried:

```
<video controls="" src="C:\Users\SIVA\Videos\The.Boss.Baby.2017.720P.Bluray.X264-[Yts.Ag]-1-1-1.m4v" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It works well on Chrome, Edge, IE, but not in Firefox. Instead it shows:

> No video with supported format and mime type found.

But it supports youtube videos. How can I fix the issue in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

The firefox cannot open `.m4v` file, however, you can wrap it to the `object` tag to let some plugin deal with it.

See the answer to the [question in mozila support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994666#question-reply) for more details.

Comment: You can also convert the file to an mp4 or something firefox supports